# Should there be an option for an OP not to receive his question comments (per case)?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

There are two particular cases of *comments discussions*.

One is when you wish to direct a private comment to a particular individual (this has been discussed and was voted down, as I see, although I still think it should be reevaluated).

The other is, when a discussion grows (very often in an irrelevant direction in view of the question), and you, as an original question poster, are getting all of those comments in your notice box.

This is not a rare occurrence, especially with high view questions.

Should there be an option for a question/answer owner to disable receiving notifications on comments on specific ones if their own posts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The notifications system is one of those features of SO that has been beaten to death. People have argued and argued over how the system should work, and we really haven't gotten any feedback from the devs.

To answer your question, there 'should' be a method for controlling what you receive notifications on.

Many people have came up with ideas about how this should work. I think at this point people have just given up. It is like the sliding timer on comments. People hate it, but the devs won't budge.

(Yes, I'm purposefully putting the devs in a bad light here. They are awesome, I appreicate what they do for the site and I know they have a lot of other stuff to do, but more feedback on these issues that have been around for a long time would be nice.)

Comment: You could write a greasemonkey script to .. ah never mind.